# Graphic card and GPU power Source

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, gpu

I have recently bought a new graphic card, and after inserting it into the PC I discover it need an auxiliary power source:

[image: Graphic Card]

The thing is, I no not have a cable 'ready' for this.

I have another socket with 2x3 connectors:

[image: MotherBord]

I could connect these two using a cable like this:

[image]

but as you see, this socket is already occupied with a cable from the power supply. Something is getting power this way, so I can not just remove the connector. And even if I did, the power comes *from* the connector, not from the socket.

I was thinking about buying the cable mentioned, and then cut off the 2x3 connector and put the wires in the existing connector, thus splitting it up.

The question is, is this the way to do it?
Or am I totally wrong, and this must be solved in a complete other way?

Thanks in advance and merry Christmas/happy holidays to all.

Comment: You need a different power supply or a card that doesn’t require PCIe power

Comment: The 6->8 cable would work if it came from the correct power supply ***and*** the GPU doesn't require more than 150W total. PCIe can supply 75W, 6-pin 75W, 8-pin 150W You need a new PSU, with the correct 8-pin 150W output, or risk crashing under load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purchase a power supply designed for gaming. These have plenty of the additional power hookups.

Comment: I actually tried with a split cable, and the PC wouldn't even start up.

Following this advise partly, I bought an extra PSU and used this for only the graphic card. Worked like a breeze.